# multiple issues after joining domain over remote site to site tunnel to another corporate envirement

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, wifi

I'm facing issues with multiple users after joining them to domain over site to site tunnel,
the company i'm joining its users has an Active directory which has their accounts to connect to corporate wifi, also as their DNS server which holds all their applications, on my part, we need to join the team we work with to our domain, in the process of joining some of them here's the issues:

1- We managed with their IT team to add our Domains Addresses in their dns server and nat our ips to connect to their lan so we don't add the domain ip on the host everytime we do this process.
- Nat works fine, Dns also, but note that they added the ip's of the domain not the natted ips as a conditional forwarder record, nonetheless we still cannot join the host with this error

```
Note: This information is intended for a network administrator. If you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator that you received this information, which has been recorded in the file C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.

DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain "domain.com"

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.com

The following domain controllers were identified by the query: dc3.domain.com
dc1.domain.com

However no domain controllers could be contacted.

Common causes of this error include:

- Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.

- Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.
```

2- some of the users fails to authenticate to wireless network on the domain user if we join them over wifi
I tried the following to resolve this issue but it didn't work:

```
   - removed our dns server and readded their dns server manually
   - reset network
   - tried to remove the domain and try again
   - recreated the network profile
```

3- if i don't have the switch user option on one of the laptops, i can't log in with their domain credentials... this is a laptop issue i guess

so my questions is
1- we allowed DNS 53 tcp and udp for the other team to be able to resolve our domain name, anything else we need to do on our domain?

2- any idea what could be the wireless connection problem.
3- our domain and theirs have the same usernames practically,  does that cause conflicts? and how?

Comment: That message is self-explanatory. The client cannot contact the host in the DNS record returned by the server for LDAP connectivity.

Comment: thanks for your reply! okay i understand, we are now trying to change the records of their dns server and we will test